# Filter day time column rules using a date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table, wherein the columns corresponds to the days of the week together with fromTime to toTime. I was wondering if how can I filter the table by a date. I have this code below. The date must return row 3 since it's the first one that satisfies the rule.

My table property is like this:

| Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | FromTime | ToTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 00:02:00 | 23:59:59 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 00:01:00 | 23:59:59 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 00:00:00 | 23:59:59 |

With a sample date like `'2022-03-03 00:00:00.0000000'`, it will satisfy row 3 since it's a Thursday and it's within fromTime and toTime

I was thinking of using the `DAY()` and `DATEPART()` function like the sample below but I can't think of a way to do it.

```
SELECT day ('2022-03-03 00:00:00.0000000') as Day
      , DATEPART (HOUR,'2022-03-03 01:30:00.0000000') as FromTime
      , DATEPART (HOUR,'23:59:59.0000000') as ToTime
```

**Result:**

| Day | FromTime | ToTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 23 |

*edit: removed image

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors(/data) when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: 1) Yes, posting the query and sample data *as text* makes it much easier to assist you.  2) *"since it's the first one that satisfies the rule"*  What "rule" is that? Do you mean find rows that match the current date and time?

Comment: When changing the picture to some text, please also explain why row 4 satisfies the rule.  You did not explain how this rule works, I do see `Dat 3` but what is the first day of the week? (You cannot expect everyone to have the same first day of the week, but it would be nice if that is the case....)

Comment: There aren't even 4 rows in your data now, so how can row 4 satisfy the rule, when there is no row 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query would probably be simpler if the day of week were a single column, storing a number. But if you have to work with the existing structure, try identifying the day of week number, then compare it against each "day" column:

```
DECLARE @DOW INT 
SET @DOW = ((DatePart(dw, getDate()) + @@DATEFIRST-1) % 7+1);

SELECT *
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  FromTime <= CAST(getDate() AS TIME)
AND    ToTime >= CAST(getDate() AS TIME)
AND  ( 
       (  @DOW = 2 AND Monday = 1 ) 
       OR
       (  @DOW = 3 AND Tuesday = 1 )
       OR
       (  @DOW = 4 AND Wednesday = 1 )
       OR
       (  @DOW = 5 AND Thursday = 1 )
       OR
       (  @DOW = 6 AND Friday = 1 )
)
```

| Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | FromTime | ToTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 00:00:00.0000000 | 23:59:59.0000000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d1662bb7cec3b5d876bc542824e18533)*

Comment: You're welcome. I considered dynamic sql, but felt it was too heavy weight for this task :) Also it could potentially break if the config settings changed.

Comment: @Khen - Out of curiosity, did you delete your previous comment here - or was it removed by some automatic S.O. process?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @dotw NVARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @sqlInsert NVARCHAR(255)

SET @requestDate = '2022-03-03 00:00:00.0000000'
SET @dotw = datename(w, @requestDate)
SET @sql = 'select * from [YourTable] where [YourTable].' + QUOTENAME(@dotw) + ' = 1'  
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

My answer. The only problem here is storing the result of the exec inside a cte.